# css animation for height increment of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

Generally, if we go to Facebook page and, press the keyboard shortcut `shift+?`
we will get this help tab. It has animation where it grows its height.. I want the CSS for that. I did the CSS but it is not working.

```
.slidingbox
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 45px;
    left: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    height: calc(100% - 45px);;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color:white;
    animation: example 4s linear ;
}



@keyframes example 
{
    0%   { height:0px;}
    50%  { height: 300px;  }
   100% { height: 500px; }
  }
```

It is not working because initially I have content in my div, therefore content is overloading.

I would like an answer where `jQuery` is not used

Comment: overflow:hidden ? and add `forwards` to the animation

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xt29ma4e/) could help?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to animate the height, but the height can be dynamic, transition the `max-height` in CSS.

```
.slidingbox
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 45px;
    left: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slidingbox.active {
    max-height: 99999px;
}
```

Be sure to use a max-height that you know it will never have.